# Where can I get a Ruby 1.8.6 for Centos OS

Tags: ruby, centos

Can anyone tell me where I can find a Ruby 1.8.6 so I can istall it in my Centos 5 machine?

Thank you.

Comment: This isn't a question for SuperUser?

Answer (score 12):

Download tarball with your version of Ruby from [here](ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8)

```
tar -xjvf ruby-1.8.6-pxxx.tar.bz2
cd ruby-1.8.6
./configure
make
make install
```

I had to do exactly what you are asking for, I just used version 1.8.7

Comment: +1! The only one who has suggested the only standard method to install a GNU pakage!

Comment: This is ridiculous - the whole point of using RPM-based system is to stick to RPMs, not building and supporting packages by yourself...

Comment: @GreyCat. The question was 'How I can find and install Ruby 1.8.6?'.  This answers it, isn't it?  Also, I do not pretend that this is the only solution available, only that this is the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

You probably want this:

"To use with yum, create /etc/yum.repos.d/ruby.repo and add the following:"

```
[ruby]
name=ruby
baseurl=http://repo.premiumhelp.eu/ruby/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=0
```

————————————————————————–

"Sample usage:"

```
yum --enablerepo=ruby list *RUBY*
```

Googleage: http://krnjevic.com/wp/?p=75

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. The 'sample usage' was not supported by my version of yum so I set enabled=1 in the .repo file.

Comment: the "sample usage" should be --enablerepo (two hypens, not one).

Comment: For those yum neophytes, the --enablerepo=ruby needs to be added to all subsequent yum commands

Comment: This repository may no longer work for you. I found Ruby in the CentOS base repository.

However, since our machine runs Cpanel, I had to edit /etc/yum.conf to remove ruby* from the "exclude=" list, so that I could use yum to install it.

Answer (score 5):

```
yum erase ruby ruby-libs
rpm -Uvh http://rbel.co/rbel5
yum install ruby
```

More info:
http://rbel.frameos.org/

Answer (score 1):

```
yum install ruby
```

If this will not install the Ruby for you, add appropriate repository to yum.

If the Ruby version in repositories is outdated, get the source, build, install by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

RPM for CentOS 5.1, x86:
http://repo.premiumhelp.eu/ruby/RPMS/ruby-1.8.6.111-1.i686.rpm

Failing that, the source code is available from the Ruby site, and you can compile and install it:
ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8/ruby-1.8.6.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

"To use with yum, create /etc/yum.repos.d/ruby.repo and add the following:"

[ruby]
name=ruby
baseurl=http://repo.premiumhelp.eu/ruby/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=0

Then: 
yum --enablerepo=ruby list *RUBY*

And:
yum update ruby -y

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to install ruby with the [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) utility, which lets you easily switch between versions.

*Note:* On CentOS 5, at least, RVM compiles of Ruby barf because autoconf is too old. There are instructions for fixing this [here](http://beginrescueend.com/packages/autoconf/)

Answer (score 0):

you can install ruby and all its dependencies including Gems withi this [bash script](http://github.com/albertsj1/Misc-Scripts/raw/master/install_gems.sh)

Comment: That just installs whatever rpm Centos has, which is not the version the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The previous repos posted only had the i686 package, this is the repo I'm using for x86_64

```
[ruby]
name=ruby
baseurl=http://centos.karan.org/el5/misc/testing/x86_64/RPMS/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=0
```

Answer (score 0):

The [yum repo](http://repo.premiumhelp.eu/ruby/) at repo.premiumhelp.eu/ruby/ is DOA.

I found another CentOS-compatable [yum repo at rubyworks.rubyforge.org/redhat/](http://rubyworks.rubyforge.org/redhat/) with full instructions [here](http://rubyworks.rubyforge.org/installation/centos.html). They explicitly support RHEL/CentOS 4 & 5, but not 6 (yet)

Comment: This repo did not work for me either. Could you doublecheck and correct the link?

Comment: There was a typo in the URL, fixed now.